# Does weka balance the train/test sets across classes in cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

When I perform a n-fold cross validation on m classes, in each fold, are the train and test sets balanced? By balanced, I mean to ask if there are (nearly) the same set of samples from each class in train and test sets.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand this part correctly:

> I mean to ask if there are (nearly) the same set of samples from each class in train and test sets.

... I think you are referring to *stratified* cross validation: where the class proportions for each fold is the same as the class proportions of the entire data set.

Yes, it is certainly possible in Weka, but you may want to consult the documentation. Might these help?

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+(Java+approach)

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/filters/supervised/instance/StratifiedRemoveFolds.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'm aware that one can do it. But I was wondering what weka does when we do cross validations in experimenter.

Comment: Weka does do stratified cross-validation when using the GUI (Weka Explorer) by default. This can be verified by looking at your *Classifier output* text and seeing the phrase `=== Stratified cross-validation ===`. Hope this helps.